# Tengo un error al subir proyecto laravel a web000hosting

Tags: laravel

El error que me da es del tipo 500 error, y el error es este:

Warning: require(/storage/ssd5/821/17448821/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd5/821/17448821/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/storage/ssd5/821/17448821/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /storage/ssd5/821/17448821/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:71 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd5/821/17448821/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(61): composerRequire26ff1592e62226af8eafc49f78e30c24() #1 /storage/ssd5/821/17448821/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit26ff1592e62226af8eafc49f78e30c24::getLoader() #2 /storage/ssd5/821/17448821/public_html/index.php(34): require('...') #3 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd5/821/17448821/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71

Ya probe ejecutando composer update, antes de subir los archivos del proyecto al host y la versión de php del host es 8.00

Comment: quien dijo que el director de tu local esta en el mismo path que en el servidor???

Comment: Habia usado el mismo procedimiento que use esta vez, para subir otro sistema al mismo host y no tuve problema con el direccionamiento, podrias ser mas especifico por favor

Comment: cual es el procedimiento que dices que has seguido... la verdad todos los errores que se ven hacen referencia a que no ha encontrado los directorios donde se supone que deberian estar...

Comment: la misma guia de 000webhost, la cual tambien segui la primera vez usando laravel para subir un proyecto y no me dio problemas https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/deploy-laravel-project-on-000webhost/127323

Comment: todos los errores que se ven hacen referencia a que no ha encontrado los directorios donde se supone que deberían estar; en cuanto a tu proyecto es muy amplio para poder reproducir ese error en especifico y se complica la situacion, no meque mas nada que decirte; si es posible y tienes acceso a ese host por SSH intenta replicar la instalación pero todo lo que sea referente a composer ejecútalo por ssh en el host y no en tu local. incluso el mismo FAQ de la guia te dice que hay limitaciones para cuentas gratuitas: https://i.imgur.com/YaiiwrD.png

Comment: si, no encuentra el boostrap.php en el archivo auto_load files, pero cuando manualmente voy a ver, si lo veo ahi, supongo que tendre que usar otro hosting

Comment: lo que pasa como te decia es que no todas la carpetas son identicas

Comment: por ejemplo esta directorio se encuentra en tu host: `/storage/ssd5/821/17448821/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php80/`